# How do I return multiple Strings from a for loop in Java?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, return, break

I'm using a for loop, and it needs a return a String every time through the loop, but using "return" breaks the loop and Eclipse throws up an "Unreachable Code" error. Any suggestions

Comment: Without knowing what you have done, it is hard to fix the code.

Comment: please let us know what the situation exactly is.

Comment: you better post your code here, let us fix it .. :)

Comment: You could return an array (`String[]`) or a `List<String>` instead

Comment: You could concatenate the String's into a single String using something like `StringBuilder` through the loop

Comment: Is anything supposed to happen when `counter == 25` ?

Comment: @DavidWallace is the counter ever going to get to 25...??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your logic is broken

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < possibleAnswers.length; counter++){
    // This condition will be meet immediately because 0 is less then 25...
    if (counter < 25){
        return alpha[counter] + ": " + possibleAnswers[counter] + "\n";
    }
    // Meaning it is impossible for the program to ever reach this line...
    if (counter >= 26){
        return alpha[26] + a + ": " + possibleAnswers[counter] + "\n";
        a++;
    }
}
```

I  think you might be better of trying something like...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(25);
for (int counter = 0; counter < possibleAnswers.length; counter++){
    if (counter < 25){
        sb.append(alpha[counter] + ": " + possibleAnswers[counter] + "\n");
    }
    if (counter >= 26){
        sb.append(alpha[26] + a + ": " + possibleAnswers[counter] + "\n");
        a++;
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

**UPDATE working example**

```
String possibleAnswers[] = new String[30];
String alpha[] = new String[30];

for (int index = 0; index < 30; index++) {
    possibleAnswers[index] = "Happy " + index;
    alpha[index] = Integer.toString(index);
}

int a = 0;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(25);
for (int counter = 0; counter < possibleAnswers.length; counter++) {
    if (counter < 25) {
        sb.append(alpha[counter]).append(": ").append(possibleAnswers[counter]).append("\n");
    }
    if (counter >= 26) {
        sb.append(alpha[26]).append(a).append(": ").append(possibleAnswers[counter]).append("\n");
        a++;
    }
}

System.out.println(sb);
```

Which outputs

```
0: Happy 0
1: Happy 1
2: Happy 2
3: Happy 3
4: Happy 4
5: Happy 5
6: Happy 6
7: Happy 7
8: Happy 8
9: Happy 9
10: Happy 10
11: Happy 11
12: Happy 12
13: Happy 13
14: Happy 14
15: Happy 15
16: Happy 16
17: Happy 17
18: Happy 18
19: Happy 19
20: Happy 20
21: Happy 21
22: Happy 22
23: Happy 23
24: Happy 24
260: Happy 26
261: Happy 27
262: Happy 28
263: Happy 29
```

Comment: It is telling me that I can not make a static reference to a non-static method when i try to do sb.append(String)

Comment: First line of example `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(25);`.  You need create an instance of `StringBuilder` before you can use it

Comment: I have the line StringBuilder choices = new StringBuilder(""); Now it's saying unreachable code again and i have exactly what you have minus the return statement

Comment: Works fine for me.  I've added a working example (fudged the data)

Comment: Works fine for me, outputs `A: one`, `B: two`, `C: three`, `D: four`. Make sure you're recompile your code. Are you using an IDE?  If so which one?

Comment: And I tried replacing all of the "+" with ".append(xxxxx)" and that didn't help either

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17275/discussion-between-cheesery-and-madprogrammer)

Answer (score 2):

If returning an `ArrayList<String>`, isn't right for your application, this sounds like a job for a call-back function. Define a call-back interface:

```
public interface StringDelivery {
    public void processString(String aString);
}
```

Then in your loop you can call back:

```
public void loopThroughStrings(StringDelivery callback) {
    for (. . .) {
        String nextString = . . .
        callback.processString(nextString);
    }
}
```

You can then call this with any object that implements the interface.

EDIT:

If you're computing a bunch of strings but need to return them as a single string, then you can put them in an array and then use `Arrays.toString(Object[] array)` to convert the entire array to a single String:

```
int n = <number of strings>
String[] strings = new String[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    strings[i] = <i-th string>
}
return Arrays.toString(strings);
```

The return value will be formatted with the list elements separated by ", " and enclosed in square brackets: "[]".

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use an ArrayList to store all your strings.

And then return the ArrayList after your for loop has completed. Something like.

```
String returnString = "";

for loop ....{
   returnString = returnString + " " + someNewString;
 }


return returnString
```

Comment: This is being used in a toString so I can't return a list

Comment: @cheesery You could, you would just need to format the list of values once they return

Comment: I updated the pseudo code.  Simplest way is to build up a long string in the loop.   You would want to use StringBuffer instead if the String is really long.

Comment: @digidigo I see where you're going with this, but aren't Strings immutable

Comment: Yes they are.  the code assigns a new object to returnString on every iteration of the loop.  Use StringBuffer if you are going through the loop more than just a few time.

Comment: @digidigo Use StringBuilder over StringBuffer (in this context) as it is generally faster (StringBuffer is synchronized, StringBuilder is not)

Comment: @cheesery The logic of your look is broken (not to blow my own horn, but check my answer). You loop will never be able to reach the second condition

Comment: MadProgrammer's answer looks correct to me.  Perhaps you re-post your updated code.  You shouldn't get unreachable code.

Comment: @MadProgrammer  yes StringBuilder is better , thanks for that.

Comment: I updated my code, now being told "The method StringBuilder(String)" is undefined

Comment: You want to use the append method on choices.  Check out @MadProgrammer's answer.  It has exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why to complicate matters .. just return an array of string

```
 public String[] function1()
 {
    String[] str1 new String(10);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    { 
          str1[i] ="string"+i;
    }
    return str1;
 }
```

Comment: You can also use ArrayList Class to add list of Strings to it

Comment: This is being used in a toString, so I can only return Strings

Answer (score 0):

You should consider returning an array of String from the method.

Just to correct a for loop does not return anything. Its the function that is returning a value.

Lastly its difficult to comment as its not clear what you are trying to achieve.